# Jquery Autocomplete: combobox + accent folding

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, combobox, diacritics, folding

I am trying to mix the Jquery Ui Autocomplete combobox and accent folding examples, but it seems to be beyond my skills. I have tried to replace the mentions to 'text' by 'normalize(text)' in the combobox example but no cigar.

Combobox example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Accent Folding example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#folding

**Update:**

I found the problem: the REGEX object was case-insensitive, but my normalize function wasn't.

Now I have a lesser problem: the code provides the well know text-highlight function as shown next:

```
if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(normal) || matcher.test(text))) {
  return {
    label: text.replace(
    new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
    value: text,
    option: this
  };
}
```

Which is fine when the user types accented text, but can't highlight if the input is non-accented. Would there be a work around that, so that the text would be hightlit even when the user types without accents?

Thank you!

Comment: If you got an example in jsFiddle etc of this that would help a lot, this is kind of a complicated / specific situation

Comment: Thank you @mcpDESIGNS, I didn't know jsFiddle! I figured my first question out but I'm going to use jsFiddle next time!

Comment: Anytime. jsFiddle is a lifesaver

Answer (score -1):

I found some solution:

```
if(this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(normalize(text)) || matcher.test(text)))
```